# Socket.io Android SSL Usage

Tags: android, node.js, ssl, socket.io, openssl

I can't use ssl on my android project. I try everything but i didn't find anything.
I use this library: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.socket/socket.io-client/1.0.0

My code block is that ;

```
IO.Options options = new IO.Options();
                options.secure = true;
                options.path="web-live";
                options.reconnection=true;
                options.upgrade=true;
                    options.query="WebToken="+WebToken+"&&userName="+userName+"&&LoginType=2&&Version="+version;

                     socket = IO.socket("https://example.com:1234", options);
```

I use this code but the ssl doesn't work

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Socket.io client in android connection with HTTPS protocol failed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37826728/socket-io-client-in-android-connection-with-https-protocol-failed)

Comment: I used it too but its doesn't work sir..